# How do I continue the scheme to find the Hermite polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, hermite-polynomials

Please help me comlete the scheme for finding the Hermite polynomial. I was given: f(o)=2, f´(0)=1, p(1)=3, p(2)=10.
I solved the problem as follows [image], but at the end I get two 2s, whish give 0 in difference. What derivaitive do I need to take next to complete this exercise?

Comment: You jump from notation $f$ to notation $p$ ? Which are which ? Besides, you use an algorithm (giving rise to the tree) that surely is described somewhere : say where you have found it, or its name...

Comment: I think it`s a scheme of divided differences. I looked at many examples and there were options with both f and p

Answer (score 0):

Now you apply the Newton interpolation formula
$$
p(x)=f(0)+f[0,0]x+f[0,0,1]x^2+f[0,0,1,2]x^2(x-1).
$$
As the last coefficient is zero, the interpolation polynomial is only quadratic.